# C++ probability calculating program works when bookmarked in Visual Studio but does not work when run without a bookmark

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Before I get into details about the code let me explain the issue. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 to compile and run this code. This code executes perfectly when I bookmark any line from the function that calculates the probability. But when I don't bookmark any line or bookmark some lines from the main function the program doesn't work. By doesn't work I mean it gives the probability as either 100% or 0% no matter how many times I run it. The answer is 50% so the probability should be close to 50%. (When I simulated it 300 times while bookmarked it gave 42%) It seems like the issue is memory related. But I'm only a CS student yet so I am really just guessing at this point. Any type of feedback or solution is appreciated.

Let me explain what the code is suppose to do. My friend recently asked me a probability question. I was not able to solve it using a certain type of logic that would make it very easy to solve. So I decided to make a small program that would calculate the odds of it by simulating it a given number of time. So here is the question.

"There are 100 seats on a plane. The first passenger has lost his ticket. He doesn't know which seat is his. So he sits randomly. Everybody after this person comes to the plane one by one. If their seat is empty they sit to their designated seats. If their seat is occupied they sit randomly. What is the probability of the last person being able to sit on his designated seat?"

Here is all of the code with comments on how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

#define PlaneCapacity 100                           //Plane capacity is now changeable. It helped me discover that this number is irrelevant to the answer of the question

using namespace std;

int PlacePeople(int SimNumber);

int SimNumber;
int Seat;
int PersonNo;
int SuccessNo = 0;
int Seats[PlaneCapacity];
int LatestSeat;

int main(){
    double Probability;
    cout << "Please enter the number of times you want the simulation to run:" << endl;
    cin >> SimNumber;
    PlacePeople(SimNumber);                         // Function that does the calculation
    Probability = (SuccessNo * 100) / (SimNumber);  //Calculate the probability in precentage form
    cout << "Probability: ";
    cout << Probability << endl;
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;                            //Exit with success...I wish :(
}

int PlacePeople(int SimNumber){
    for (int a = 0; a < SimNumber; a++){            //Number of simulations. The code doesn't work when I bookmark this line
        Seats[PlaneCapacity] = { 0 };               //Array with elements that corresponds to the plane seats. Code works when I bookmark any line from this point onward. This line included.
        PersonNo = 1;                               //Last person that sit down
        LatestSeat = 0;                             //The seat the last person sit on
        srand(time(NULL));
        Seat = rand() % PlaneCapacity + 1;          //Randomizer that determines where the first passanger will sit
        if (Seat == 1){                             //If he sits in his place everything is golden!
            SuccessNo++;
        }
        if (1 < Seat && Seat < PlaneCapacity){      //If he doesn't sit in his place or the last passengers place things gets a bit messy
            Seats[Seat - 1] = PersonNo;             //Put him to his seat e.g 45th seat
            for (int b = 1; b < Seat - 1; b++){     //Everybody until that seat (43 people, from 2 to 44) sits in their regular place. 45th person has no where to sit :(
                PersonNo++;
                Seats[PersonNo - 1] = PersonNo;
            }
            PersonNo++;
            LatestSeat = PersonNo;
            while (PersonNo < PlaneCapacity){       //The same process for the first passanger will be repeated until the last person is seated

                Seat = rand() % (PlaneCapacity - LatestSeat + 1) + LatestSeat;      //I tried to lower the random number interval so the code would work a little more efficiently
                if (Seat == LatestSeat){                                            //The first guys seat might still be empty. So my interval is 1 bigger than it should be. Normally
                    SuccessNo++;                                                    //i would just place him when the random number says 1. But to make the interval shorter I now place the
                    break;                                                          //next guy to the first seat when the random number generator gives the latest seat number
                }                                                                   //So in my example if the random number is 45 I place the 45th guy to the 1st seat. Once the first seat is occupied
                Seats[Seat - 1] = PersonNo;                                         //We are guarenteed to have the last guy sit in his place so code can exit after that and increase the success counter
                for (int b = LatestSeat; b < Seat - 1; b++){
                    PersonNo++;
                    Seats[PersonNo - 1] = PersonNo;
                }
                PersonNo++;
                LatestSeat = PersonNo;
            }
        }
    }
    return SuccessNo;       //return the number of succesfull attepmts to the main function
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try moving the srand call up to main. You shouldn't have to reseed the RNG before every call.

Comment: When you say bookmark do you mean breakpoint?

Comment: `Seats[PlaneCapacity] = { 0 };` invokes undefined behavior. You're writing to an element one-past your array allowance. You probably wanted `std::fill(std::begin(Seats), std::end(Seats), 0);` (though it appears nearly all of your globals should be locals and/or parameters). And I concur with Wayne. that seed should be called *once*, likely at the startup of `main()`.

Comment: @WayneTanner I tried your suggestion. And it worked. I feel silly now. Thanks!

Comment: @WhozCraig I simply googled how to fill an array with zeroes. I also remember seeing the one you suggested. It was working already. But I applied your suggestion anyways. Still worked fine. I assume it is the more ideal way of doing it?

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` Seed only 1 time in main. Never ever in a loop.

Comment: @RetiredNinja In visual studio when I click on the left side of an line it puts a bookmark on it. When I say compile and run the code it pauses every time when it comes to a bookmark and it allows me to check the values of variables and etc. That was the bookmark I was talking about.

Comment: @GoktugO It has nothing to do with ideal or otherwise; the code you have is ill-formed and invokes undefined behavior as-is, plain and simple. It needs to be fixed. Don't confuse *observed* behavior with *defined* behavior. Just because it seems to work doesn't mean its right. That it works rather than failing hard-and-early instills a false confidence, unfortunately.

Comment: A bookmark will not stop while debugging. A breakpoint will. Clicking on the far left side of the ide in Visual Studio 2010 adds a breakpoint (looks like a red filled in circle) for me.

Comment: @drescherjm Oh. My bad then. I'm pretty new with this software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, move the srand call to main prior to the call to PlacePeople(). When you don't break into the debugger, I think the function is executing fast enough that all iterations of the look get the same random number. To verify this, try printing out the value of seat and see if it is distributed randomly over available seats or not.